# Is my code correct? Connect to SQL Server. Using VB6 / Access2003

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vb6, connection, authentication

Connect to SQL Server via (ODBC System DSN?) (No WinNT Auth) using VB6 / Access2003.

I don't know if my code** is correct. Could someone give me an example that do the following:

- Connect to SQLServer 2005/2008 (Normal and Express)
- Connect via ODBC (or would it work without ODBC?)
- Using SQL Authentification instead of NT Authentification
- No Trusted Connection available (Username / Password needed)

Background info. We wrote a program which connects to a SQL Server via ODBC - System DSN.
It works quietly good IF the connection is trusted  OR IF the user is in the same domain. (Using Windows NT Authorisation instead of SQL-Authorisation).

**Now to my problem**:
When someone's got no Windows NT Authorisation, you must choose SQL Authorisation, set up Username and Password (created inside the SQL Server). (For example. The master machine is running SQL Server on Win XP, Vista or Win 7. Without being in a Domain).

Now this happens when I try to connect my piece of code with the new ODBC Connection. (Which is using SQL Auth --> User/Pass). Everytime I open the program, I must enter the password for the Connection once to connect my Tables with my Access Database.

ConnectionStrings.com didn't helped me.

*My connectionstrings for a SQL Authentificated Connection looks like*:

**`ODBC;DATABASE=MyDatabase;DESCRIPTION=Connection to my Database;DSN=ODBCConnection;OPTION=0;PWD=MyPass;PORT=1433;SERVER=MyNormalMachine\SQLEXPRESS;UID=MyUser`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998924/sql-server-2008-odbc-connection-problems AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601034/odbc-continually-prompts-for-password

Comment: Thanks Remou for the Reply, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601034/odbc-continually-prompts-for-password doesn't give me a proper Solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998924/sql-server-2008-odbc-connection-problems seems legit but its not the good idea to save it in readable text (we would save passes crypted and decrypt them while building the Connection String) is there another possibility for connection with SQL Server with SQL Authentification where you send the password by hand?

Comment: I am afraid I do not quite get that. What do you mean "by hand"? I thought you did not wish to enter a password?

Comment: my wish is it to save the password inside the local database, open those field with the pass in it, set it into the connectionstring to get the other tables from SQL Server into my local Database.

Comment: How are we going to tell if your code is correct if you didn't include it in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating a connection string as follows:

```
sConnect = "driver={SQL Server};server=" & gsServer & ";" & "database=" & sDatabaseName & ";uid=" & sUserName & ";pwd=" & sPassword
```